# Cannot disable "javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web._vs.server" traces in Glassfish

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3

I set SEVERE level for logger javax.enterprise.system.container.web.
Server was restarted.
But there are still INFO traces in GF server.log file for this logger.

```
[#|2015-02-20T15:55:24.887+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web._vs.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-28;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext|#]
```

Is it possible to disable INFO "javax.enterprise.system.container.web" traces at all?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, did you make sure the logging level is correctly set in the `logging.properties` file? Maybe the admin UI has a bug.

You can manually change the value in the file `<GLASSFISH_HOME>/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties`.

Just change the value for `javax.enterprise.system.container.web` to `SEVERE` and save the file, this should work on-the-fly, you don't have to restart Glassfish.

**See also:**

- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Administration Guide - Setting Log Levels](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ghgwi/index.html)

Comment: Should I modify logging.properties for domain or for node? I need to disable logging for one node only.

Comment: I only tried it for the domain but I guess it should also work for a node only.

Comment: Level is correct for node. But I sill can see following traces in /gf/nodes/cmp_localhost_01/prod_0/logs/server.log: [#|2015-02-26T13:01:53.681+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web._vs.server|_ThreadID=112;_ThreadName=Thread-28;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot,ViewId: /index.xhtml][Class: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlPage,Id: mainPageId][Class: com.company.prod.l.webui.impl.ApplicationWindowUIComponent,Id: j_id19]

Comment: You can try if it works if you set it for the whole domain, maybe there is a bug with the handling of specific logging properties for different nodes.